# Strategies for linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider I have the following equations.
Is there a faster way for me to solve the system without going through a series of substitutions?

$$-20a+13b+13c=0$$
$$10a-26b+13c=0$$
$$10a-13b-16c=0$$
$$a+b+c=1$$

Comment: Faster? Not really. But neater, if you organize the equations into an augmented matrix and use elementary row operations to bring it to reduced form.

Comment: Have you heard of gaussian elimination? Note that you only need three equations and check with the fourth.

Comment: (a) Add the first three equations together. (b) subtract the third equation from the second. Consider the outcomes of (a) and (b) - note both eliminate the variable $a$

Comment: The elementary row operations (mentioned by @GerryMyerson) are essentially a neat way of adding together multiples of the equations with the goal of making the coefficients in front of variables $0$.  For example, if you add the 1st and 3rd equation the coefficient of $b$ becomes 0.  Repeat, repeat... until you have a single equation with a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

with $$c=1-a-b$$ you will get
$$33a=13$$
$$3a+39b=13$$
$$26a+3b=16$$
this system has no solution.

Comment: I get a solution :/

Comment: no this system has definitively no solution